# ¿Cómo puedo crear un gráfico de barras usando ggplot2 con dos variables discretas?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image: Este es el gráfico que me gustaría conseguir(lo hice con Excel)]

Hola, en primer lugar pedir disculpas por supuestos errores que puediera cometer al realizar la pregunta, es mi primera pregunta aquí. 
Llevo unas horas buscando una forma de representar unos datos con ggplot2 y no encuentro la solución.

Tengo un data set con datos de clientes llamado training que incluye, entre otras, un par de variables llamadas ProdBought (contiene 0,1,2,3,4,5,6) y Sales (contiene 0 y 1), dependiendo de si el cliente compró algún producto y/o realizó alguna compra.
Quiero hacer un gráfico de barras de manera que en el eje x aparezca ProdBought y en el eje y todos aquellos clientes que han comprado un producto, dos, tres o los que sean. A la vez, en cada barra me gustaría representar la suma de aquellos clientes cuyas sales = 0 y los que sales = 1.

He intentado esto :

```
ggplot(training, aes(ProdBought), fill=Sales) + geom_bar()
```

pero solo me muestra la suma total por ProdBought sin diferenciar entre sales=0 o sales = 1.

Adjunto una imagen del gráfico que me gustaría conseguir.

¿Me podríais ayudar?
Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: Hola Domingo, bienvenido. Esta es la página de stackoverflow en español y tu pregunta está formulada en inglés. Deberías traducir tu pregunta, de lo contrario lo más probable es que sea cerrada. Puedes editar el título y el contenido de tu pregunta para hacer la traducción. De paso: es mucho más probable que recibas una respuesta adecuada si incluyes un ejemplo mínimo y reproducible del problema, incluyendo los datos necesarios. Si haces esas dos cosas seguramente obtendrás una respuesta a la brevedad. Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias, mpaladino. Es mi primera pregunta y no tengo mucha idea de cómo formularla bien. La he editado y traducido. No sé si debería incluir ejemplo del dataset.

Comment: Ya puse una respuesta completa. En el código que presentas en el ejemplo creo que el error es que `fill= Sales` está fuera del `aes()`, como sí lo está y correctamente `ProdBought`. Al esta fuera del `aes()` se mapea a una constante. De paso: en la respuesta uso `geom_col` en lugar de `geom_bar`, por es es necesario que se hagan los conteos previamente.

Comment: ¡Qué maravilla! Muchísimas gracias, mpaladino.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creamos unos datos con una estructura similar a la de los tuyos, digamos que un data.frame con dos columnas (`ProdBought` y `Sales`).

```
set.seed(2018)
datos <- data.frame(ProdBought = sample(c(0:6), size = 100, replace = TRUE), 
                    Sales = sample(c(0,1), size = 100, replace = TRUE))
```

Ahora bien, hay varias formas de hacer este gráfico en R. En este caso vamos a tratar de resolverlo usando la librería `ggplot`, que a su vez está en el metapaquete `tidyverse`. Lo vamos a hacer paso a paso: primero calcular las frecuencias de cada combinación de `ProdBought` y `Sales`. Con esas frecuencias en una estructura de datos podemos proceder a graficar.

```
library(tidyverse)
datos %>% 
  group_by(ProdBought, Sales) %>% 
  count() -> conteos
```

Que nos da este resultado intermedio:

```
conteos
# A tibble: 14 x 3
# Groups:   ProdBought, Sales [14]
ProdBought Sales     n
<int> <dbl> <int>
1          0     0     9
2          0     1    10
3          1     0     4
4          1     1    11
5          2     0    11
6          2     1     4
7          3     0     5
8          3     1     7
9          4     0    10
10         4     1     4
11         5     0     5
12         5     1     7
13         6     0     5
14         6     1     8
```

Sobre estos datos transformados vamos a hacer el gráfico, ya que por el ejemplo que das lo que te interesa es la frecuencia de compra/no compra para cada producto.

Para el gráfico tenemos que mapear qué parte del mismo va a estar controlada por cada dato. En este caso: en el eje x queremos cada valor de `ProdBought`, el eje y se controla con `n`, el conteo y por último el color de relleno se controla con `Sales`. Por último indicamos que el elemento geométrico es la columna (`geom_col()`).

```
ggplot(data = conteos, aes(x = ProdBought, y = n, fill = Sales)) + 
  geom_col()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ese es el gráfico básico. Después podemos cambiar el tema, agregar etiquetas y modificar la paleta de colores para que quede a nuestro gusto.

```
ggplot(data = conteos, aes(x = ProdBought, y = n, fill = Sales)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  geom_text(aes(label = n), 
            position = position_stack(), vjust = 2) + # Para los valores en la columna
  labs (title = "ProdBought vs. Sales", y = NULL) +   # Etiquetas del gráfico
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(legend.position = "top") +                    #Leyenda arriba
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "lightblue"))   # Colores de las barras
```

Que resulta en este gráfico que se parece bastante al de tu ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]