# Plot interactivo en R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

hace un par de días hice esta pregunta:[Cómo crear gráfico de barras](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/220648/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-crear-un-gr%C3%A1fico-de-barras-usando-ggplot2-con-dos-variables-discreta)

Ahora estoy intentando crear una gráfica interactiva en R Shiny. 
El resultado esperado es algo así:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado el siguiente código:

```
training <- read.csv("~/Desktop/training.csv")
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)



# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(


  titlePanel("Gráficas:"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for Variables 
  sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(

  selectInput(inputId = "y",
              label = "y",
              choices = "Sales",
              selected = "Sales"

  ),

  selectInput(inputId = "x",
              label = "Variable",
              choices = c( "Products Bought" = "ProdBought", 
                           "Numero de casas" = "NumCasas"
                           ),
              selected = "ProdBought")
),


# Show a plot of the generated distribution
mainPanel(
  plotOutput(outputId = "BarPlot")

    )
  )
 ))


  server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  # generate plot
  output$BarPlot <- renderPlot({

  training %>% 
  group_by(input$x, Sales) %>%
  count() -> conteos  

  ggplot(data = conteos, aes(x = input$x, y = n, fill = Sales)) + 
  geom_col() 

  })
  })

  # Run the application 
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Sin embargo, la gŕafica me queda como:
Una sola columna con todos los datos acumulados en vez de separados por ProdBought.

¿Me podríais decir qué estoy haciendo mal?
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que tienes es como las rutinas, tanto de `dplyr` como de `ggplot2`, hacen la evaluación de los parámetros recibidos. Las mismas, lo hacen de una forma conocida como, NO estándar. Esto tiene varias ventajas, pero algunas contras, entre ellas, que no es posible indicar una cadena como parámetro. Veamos un ejemplo con `dplyr` para entender esto:

```
mtcars %>%
    group_by(cyl) %>% 
    count() %>% 
    head()

# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   cyl [3]
    cyl     n
  <dbl> <int>
1     4    11
2     6     7
3     8    14
```

Lo anterior, funciona como lo esperado, notar que no tenemos que encerrar la variable `cyl` entre comillas, esto justamente es la evaluación NO estándar, `cyl` sin comillas se evalúa dentro del entorno de `mtcars` por lo que se asocia directamente a la columna de este `data.frame`,

Sin embargo si quisiéramos que la variable a agrupar, sea definida por un parámetro externo, podríamos pensar que es lógico hacer algo así:

```
var_grupo <- "cyl"
mtcars %>%
    group_by(var_grupo) %>% 
    count() %>% 
    head()

Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) : 
  Column `var_grupo` is unknown
```

Al no usar la evaluación estándar, no se logra "encontrar" la variable `var_grupo` por que no existe en entrono de evaluación de `group_by`, incluso esto:

```
mtcars %>%
    group_by("cyl") %>% 
    count() %>% 
    head()

# A tibble: 1 x 2
# Groups:   "cyl" [1]
  `"cyl"`     n
  <chr>   <int>
1 cyl        32
```

Que si bien funciona, lo hace incorrectamente, ya que agrupa todo en un solo grupo al no reconocer que `"cyl"` se corresponde con la variable del mismo nombre. Esto es justamente lo que ocurre cuando haces: `group_by(input$x, Sales)` y un problema similar ocurre con `ggplot` al hacer `.. aes(x = input$x, ...)`.

Para solucionarlo, tienes dos formas. La primera sería haciendo un bloque `If` para identificar de que variable se trata y llevar la ejecución al código que se evalúe correctamente:

```
if (input$x == "ProdBought") {
   training %>%
      group_by(ProdBought, Sales) %>%
      count() -> conteos
   ggplot(data = conteos, aes(x = ProdBought, y = n, fill = Sales)) + 
       geom_col() 
} else ...
```

Esto tiene la contra, que a medida que se incrementen las variables tu código irá creciendo en complejidad.

La otra forma, es aprovechar que tanto `dplyr` como `ggplot` tienen mecanismos para hacer evaluación estándar. En el caso de `dplyr` hay segundas versiones de muchas de las funciones del paquete, que usan la evaluación estándar, en el caso de `group_by()` existe `group_by_`. El underscore final nos indica que la función evalúa de la forma estándar. Con `ggplot`, es un poco distinto, en este caso tenemos una rutina `aes_string()` que nos permite generar el parámetro `aes()` directamente desde cadena de forma estándar.

Finalmente tu ejemplo final podría quedar así:

```
training %>%
    group_by_(input$x, "Sales") %>%
    count() %>%
    ggplot(aes_string(x = input$x, y = "n", fill = "Sales")) +
        geom_col()
```

Comentarios:

- Al usar `group_by_()` todas las variables se evalúan como si fueran cadenas, entonces, las que son fijas, como `Sales` habrá que encerrarlas con comillas.
- Algo parecido ocurre con `aes_string()`, nota que las variables fijas, ahora están encerradas con comillas.
- Como mejora adicional: se puede evitar crear la variable `conteos` ya que `ggplot` se puede integrar al proceso mediante el `%>` (pipe).

Comment: Muchas gracias, Patricio. Me ha quedado muy claro.